# Disable img require in Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, jestjs

I test react component and render it like this

```
function renderComponent() {
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <Component />   
    );
}
```

but have img tag in component what require some png

```
<img style={style} src={require('img/img.png')}/>
```

and have error when try to render it

```
Error: Cannot find module 'img/img.png'
```

So how just disable this require before render component

Comment: or maybe i can change component(delete img src) before render? how do it?

Comment: how disable this require?